# To show that $f(x)= \frac{1}{x}$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

To show that $f(x)= \frac{1}{x}$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$

**ATTEMPT**
Choose $\epsilon$ to be less than 1
Let $x_1=\delta$ and $x_2=\frac{\delta}{2}$

Then $|x_1-x_2|$ is less than $\delta$

$|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|= \frac{1}{\delta}$ which is bigger than 1(choosing $\delta$ to be less than 1)
, and so bigger than $\epsilon$

Now by Archimedian property choose

$\frac{1}{\delta}$ greater than $\epsilon$

so this violates our condition of uniform continuity

**IS THIS CORRECT ?**

Thanks

Comment: What is $\varepsilon$? I suggest you write the "epsilon-delta" definition of not being uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @Arthur can you please provide technical details?

Comment: @Arthur Actually, you don't have $\epsilon$, you choose $\epsilon$ such that for all $\delta$...

Comment: @user110822 Yes, I was a bit sloppy there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is mathematically incorrect, because you did not show what statement you want to disprove.

Your attempt is a very typical way a beginner approaches a mathematical proof, and that is to simply throw every possible thing they think is correct out. There is no structure, no story told in your proof.

Your attempt needs to start with:

> $f$ is uniformly continuous if, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,y\in(0,\infty)$, if $|x-y|<\delta$, we know that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Now, since you are disproving uniform continuity, you need to prove the statement:

> There exists a $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $\delta > 0$, there exist such $x,y$ that $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|>\epsilon$.

You do this by actually setting a certain value of $\epsilon$ (for example, $\epsilon=1$ is possible), then taking an *arbitrary* value of $\delta$ and finding the correct pair of $x,y$ to prove your point.

Remember, the statement says: There exists such an $\epsilon$ that for every $\delta$, there exists a pair $x,y$, such that something is true.

You cannot, therefore, choose your $\epsilon$ **after** you chose your $\delta$.

---

Example:

here is my proof of the statement

> There exists such an $\epsilon>0$ that for every $\delta>0$, it is true that $\epsilon <\delta$.

- Let $\delta > 0$
- Then, there exists some $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $\frac1n\leq\delta$
- Then, I choose to set $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n+1}$.
- Since $\frac1{n+1}<\frac1n\leq \delta$, I conclude that $\epsilon < \delta$ and the statement is proven.

Can you see the error in my argument?

Comment: i have proved that $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|$ is greater than epsilon, by the help of archimedian property

Comment: @TaylorTed See the last sentence of my edited post.

Comment: Yes i got the point. If i choose(in beginning) epsilon to be 1 and delta to be less than 1. Will that work>

Comment: @TaylorTed Edit your original post with the updated proof. Then we can talk whether it is now OK or not. And try to use the correct terminology (i.e., use phrases like "let us choose an arbitrary $\delta>0$."

Comment: Is error is the equal to sign. Also please check edited question

Comment: @TaylorTed You still say "chose $\frac1\delta$ greater than $\epsilon$". Your proof is still no good. You also cannot say that $\frac1\delta>1$, since you are proving your statement ***for all values of $\delta$***. You cannot choose $\delta<1$. You, again, first *SET* $\epsilon$, then you take an *arbitrary* $\delta$.

Comment: Can you please provide exact details so that i follow them and use in my next proofs

Comment: @TaylorTed That's not how this site works. We don't do work for you. We help you do your own work. I won't go solve the problem just because you don't want to put in the effort. The proof you wrote is wrong. I told you what is wrong. At least remove thos parts that are wrong.

Comment: i will think over and edit, Also this is just self learning

Comment: @TaylorTed Self learning or not, if I just tell you how to solve the problem, you will learn nothing. Again, the proof must have these stages: (0) Introduction (1) Set $\epsilon$ to some number. (2) Take an arbitrary $\delta$. (3) Find such $x,y$ that $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|>\epsilon$. (4) Conclusion.

Comment: i take epsilon to be 1. And and $x_1=\delta$ and $x_1=\delta/2$. Now $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|=\frac{1}{\delta}$. Now to disprove the unifrom continuity i have to show that $\frac{1}{\delta}$ is greater than 1.What should i do next? Thanks

Comment: @TaylorTed Instead of proving $\frac1\delta>1$ (which you cannot, since $\delta$ could be $4$), rethink your choice of $x_1,x_2$. If $\delta<1$, then your choice is good. Now, if $\delta>1$, set $x_1$ and $x_2$ to some other values.

Comment: On choosing $x_1$ to be $\frac{\delta}{n}$ and $x_2$ to be $\frac{\delta}{2n}$ . Then $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|=\frac{n}{\delta}$. So now will archimedes work ?

Comment: @TaylorTed There you go. Now all you need to do is write your whole proof from start to finish again so that it will be obvious what you did. You could also avoid Archimedes by simply saying that if $\delta>1$, you choose $x_1=\frac12$ and $x_2=\frac32$.

Comment: If i use contradiction method, then my proof will work or not?Anyways Thanks for helping. Earlier i was proving a particular case,is where i was wrong

Comment: @TaylorTed Yes, the proof can be done by contradiction. But you still need to rework it. You can write it down and I can tell you if it is OK.

Comment: +1 There are numerous answers to this particular question scattered about. I logged in to upvote your most instructive answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

After choosing your $\epsilon$, you have to find $x(\delta)$ and $y(\delta)$ such that $|x - y| < \delta$ and $|1/x - 1/y| \ge \epsilon$.

**Hint:**

Find a suitable constant $c$ such that:

$$x = \delta, y = \frac{\delta}{1 + c \delta}$$

You went wrong when you mixed up the concepts. You want to disprove uniform continuity. The statement of uniform continuity is: "$\forall $ $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists$ $\delta > 0$, such that $\forall $ $x,y$, $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

Thus, to prove a function not uniformly continuous, you should prove that:

$$\exists \ \epsilon > 0, \forall \ \delta > 0, \exists \ x,y \text{ functions of $\delta$, such that} \ |x - y| < \delta \text{ and } |f(x) - f(y)| \ge \epsilon$$

So you choose $\epsilon$ in an independent manner of $\delta$, because you don't know the delta at that stage. In other words, the choice of $\epsilon$ is what you begin the whole process with, so you can't choose it at some later time.